# Apache2 not installing necessary modules

Tags: apt, server, package-management, apache2, php

Upon removing apache2 via `sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and reinstalling it via `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install apache2`, it does not install mods it should be installing.

It returns errors such as:

```
Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/access_compat.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Errors like this are repeated ad nauseam for every .load file in mods-enabled, and removing every .load file from mods-enabled does not allow apache2 to activate, since as far as I can tell these modules are necessary for apache2's functioning. Upon checking /usr/lib/apache2/modules, there are no mods, even after repeated removing and reinstalling. Deleting /usr/lib/apache2 does not help.

Any help?

Version: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: Very rarely does Apache need to be removed and reinstalled. Could you [edit] your question to explain why this might have been necessary? It may provide a little more context about what might be preventing the modules from loading 

Comment: AFAIK the core modules are provided by the `apache2-bin` package - which should have been installed as a dependency of `apache2`, but perhaps check its status ex. `dpkg -l apache2-bin` in case something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with `sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-bin`